# How to do pivot of Column which has values like 1, 0 and -1 and count the total number

Tags: pandas, group-by, pivot

So i have column like date, Paid (it contains 1 (Yes), 0(Now) and -1(Ongoing))
now i wanted ouptut as below

```
date          1  0  -1   Total Paid0%  Paid1%
1st March    10  5   5   20     50%    50%
2nd March    5   4   1   10    40%      50%
...
```

[Please see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDKN1.png)
pd.pivot_table(df, columns = 'PAID', values = 'PAID', index = 'DATE', aggfunc = 'count')

Comment: How is count `50%` for `Paid0%` in first row?

Comment: No there are not 3 columns total there are 2 columns in which one is date and another is Paid in Paid we have 3 unique rows i.e 1(means it has paid), 0(means it has not paid) and -1
I hope you got it the data and the output

Comment: What is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: There is nothing as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df['date'], df['Paid'])
```

Then `sum` values per rows by [`DataFrame.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
tot = df1.sum(axis=1)
```

Divide columns `0,1` by sum in variable `tot`, change formating for percentages by  [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and change columns names in `rename`:

```
 df2 = (df1[[0,1]].div(tot, axis=0)
                  .applymap(lambda x: f"{x:.2%}")
                  .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Paid{x}%'))
```

Create column `Total` by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and append by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) new DataFrame `df2`:

```
final = df1.assign(Total = tot).join(df2)
print (final)
Paid       -1  0  1  Total  Paid0%  Paid1%
date                                      
1st March   1  2  2      5  40.00%  40.00%
2nd March   0  1  3      4  25.00%  75.00%
```

Comment: hey can you explain this code
and also i wanted that % in decimal like 9.34%
don't round it off

Comment: @AkshayPatil - answer was edited, for 2 decimals use `.applymap(lambda x: f"{x:.2%}")` instead `.applymap(lambda x: f"{x:.0%}")`

Comment: can you explain the code

Comment: @AkshayPatil - Code is explained in answer.